# Converting a char array to binary and returning the array

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a char array to hexadecimal and binary. Then returning those values as a char array to write it out to standard output. Since I am not allowed to use `cout` for the output, I won’t be able to use the hex IO manipulator to accomplish this. Likewise, functions from the printf family using a format of %x are not permitted either.

```cpp
constexpr char hexmap[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                           '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};

char *hexa(char buffer[],int size){
    string str;
    char *q = new char[10000];
    for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {
         char const byte = buffer[i];
         q[i] += hexmap[ ( byte & 0xF0 ) >> 4 ];
         q[i] += hexmap[ ( byte & 0x0F ) >> 0 ];
    }
    //  for (int i = 0; i < str.length();i++){
    //  q[i] = str[i];
    //  cout << q[i];
    //  }
    return q;

}

char *binary(char buffer[]){
    string n(buffer);
    int s = n.length(); 
    string t = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= s; i++)  { 
         int val = int(n[i]); 
         string bin = ""; 
         while (val > 0){
            (val % 2)? bin.push_back('1'):
                bin.push_back('0');
            val /= 2;
         }
         reverse(bin.begin(),bin.end());
             t += bin;
        }
    char *c = new char[t.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); ++i){
       c[i] = t[i];

    }
    return c;             

}
```

```
% cat file1
Hello World
% ./dog ­n 5 ­x file1
65486c6c6f
% ./dog ­n 5 ­b file1
0110010101001000011011000110110001101111
```

My Results:

```
Binary:1001000110111010010010000
Hex:lk▒▒▒beio▒kbknojbg▒▒b▒lk▒
```

Comment: Recommendations: [Read How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Make a [mcve]. Step through the code with a debugger looking for places where the program does the unexpected. Use descriptive variable names.

Comment: I don't want to get into a revert-war with you, so please explain what putty has to do with this question. Far as I can see it serves no purpose here other than as one of hundreds of possible terminal emulators.

Comment: In function `hexa()` you overwrite the upper hex digit with the lower. Use `q[2*i] += hexmap[ ( byte & 0xF0 ) >> 4 ];` and `q[2*i+1] += hexmap[ ( byte & 0x0F ) >> 0 ];` and it works. In function `binary()` you will loose leading binary zero digits. If you want the leading binary zero digits you need to loop over each of the 8 character bits and shift right during each loop cycle. Why you don't return the result as string and avoid allocating memory ?

Comment: I have to use the write function to print it out.

Comment: @hacobo *I have to use the write function to print it out* -- How does this prevent you from returning a `std::string`?  Do you believe that you can't print out a `std::string`'s contents?  There is absolutely no need for `new char []` or char pointers in your code.  Everything can be done using `std::string`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How do I print out a string using the write() function. It says it needs Write(int,const *void,size_t)

Comment: If you have a `std::string str` then you can use `write(STDOUT_FILENO, str.c_str(), str.size());`

Comment: @hacobo A string class would be almost useless if it had no way to get the data as a `char *` (or const char *) and use it.  The `c_str()` function gives you a pointer to the string data.

Comment: It looks like you are presenting two problems here. 1) Produce the binary representation of your string. 2) Produce the hexadecimal representation of your string. You might find it easier to focus and work on one at a time. Not to mention that multiple inquiries in a Stack Overflow question tend to produce results that are of no help to future visitors.